# Android Progress Dialog - Activity has leaked window DecorView

Tags: android

I am making post request using Volley and showing progress dialog. It is working fine but when we change orientation right after making post request. The app crashes with

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View:DecorView@fbad[Starting Verification Process] not attached to window manager
```

**Starting Verification Process** is the title of Progress dialog.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On destroying your activity Dismiss the dialog.

> `@Override protected void onDestroy() {
>       super.onDestroy();
>       if (pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){
>           pDialog.dismiss();
>       } }`

Answer (score 0):

first can i show your respective code. otherwise you can make to finish or dismiss your dialog as well.